# How to load JSON data in snappydata table with rowstore mode using sql query?

Tags: json, snappydata

I'm using snappydata.I have 1M rows of JSON file,i want to load that JSON file to snappydata table using sql(snappydata sql).

Answer (score 1):

Step 1)

`create external table t1 using json options(path 'location of your json file(s)');`

Step 2)

Load into a Snappy column or row table:

`create table My-in-memory-table using column as (select * from t1);`

I think, there could be some issue if your json docs are multi-line. but, there are ways to work around this.